# Vector Tools Tab Does Not Appear on QGIS 3.10.8 and QGIS 3.14.1 on Windows 7 through Remote Access VPN (They do on Windows 10)

Tags: vector, error, tools, windows-7, windows-10

I am using QGIS on my work computer which runs Windows 7. I am using remote access (VPN) to access this work computer that runs Windows 7 since I am working from home. Today I tried to use the vector tools and I cannot access any of the options from the above ribbon (see attached photo). I have tried this in both QGIS 3.10.8 and QGIS 3.14.1 and in both instances, the vector tools don't show up when I press "Vector" in the above ribbon.

I have another computer at home that runs the latest QGIS on Windows 10 and the vector tool in the above ribbon shows the vector options without a problem.

I was wondering if someone has experienced this before? I assume this might be due to the operating system or VPN? What is strange is that last week the GIS Vector tools worked fine on Windows 7 that was accessed through remote access (VPN). Is there perhaps a plugin that is not downloaded?

I am more than happy to provide any more information needed to resolve this.

[image: Ciled in red, when I press Vector, nothing shows up below. All the other ribbon options work]

Comment: Windows 7 is not a supported Operating System, please revise your question.

Comment: Thank you Mapperz.

Comment: Thank you Mapperz, I have however been using QGIS on Windows 7 for over a year at the office and never had a problem. till now I ran QGIS 3.0 on Windows 7 yesterday and it had the same problem with the vector tool.